# Java Exception since Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: java, macos

Yesterday I installed the new Mac OS "High Sierra", but since I did that,
a Java Programm of mine doesn't work anymore.

It looks like it works until the point you want to open a FileChooser and select a File.

The Exception below is shown in the Terminal.

objc[546]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff9a225a70) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x13c291cd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably file a [bug report to JAVA](http://bugreport.java.com/). Even if I am not sure about who develop the JNI code. Most likely Apple.... You could read about [crashes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html), and the _5.1.1 Crash in Native Code_ part. I can't debug since I don't have a Mac, but you should create a [mcve] to reproduce this

Comment: Hi @LukasResch I don't think this is an issue with Java. This warning is coming from Xcode console. Please check https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/17659 facing same problem and Java is not being used.