# 'Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both ...' warning in Xcode since update to macOS High Sierra

Tags: xcode, cocoa, warnings, macos-high-sierra

I am getting the following warning in the Xcode console while running (not compiling) my application since updating to High Sierra on my MacBook:

> objc[26299]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit
>   (0x7fff88339a70) and
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
>   (0x10cae0cd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I found the someone else getting this warning on [Github](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/17659), and someone who is getting it when working with Java: [Java Exception since Mac OS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601077/java-exception-since-mac-os-high-sierra)

To me the problem behaves exactly as described in the discussion on Github. It doesn't seem to produce any functional issues directly connected to it. In my case I would like to get rid of all warnings though because I am experiencing issues with my application since I updated to High Sierra.

I hope someone has found a way to tackle this warning by now.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about this. It's an Apple problem, but it's probably harmless.

Note: I'm not sure what other description could be given than what the warning says. It just means that the same class is defined in two modules. With Apple stuff, they're often identical so it doesn't matter which copy is used.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: I'm not sure what other description could be given than what the warning says. It just means that the same class is defined in two modules. With Apple stuff, they're often identical so it doesn't matter which copy is used.

Comment: Maybe we can understand which .h files or linked libraries cause the warning and remove them if they aren't used? It would be an appropriate solution. Or you mean that both implementations are included together and the problem cannot be solved in a simple way?

Comment: Just a heads-up: the problem persists in 10.13, Xcode 10, Swift 4.2.

Comment: is there something we can do tell the app which one to use (as the warning says). like in other languages `import Class from Module as A`

Comment: I wanted to add, that I'm getting this problem also when trying to write an extensibility plugin for Visual Studio for Mac (based on MonoDevelop) that uses OpenFileDialog, whether I try the Xwt version or the MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs version, reported it to the developers on GitHub. On mine, while debugging the extension from another VS instance, it causes a white rectangle to appear, obscuring my debugger view, basically making it unusable, until the CommandHandler's "Run()" method is finished, which is where all the code is based in, oh boy.

Comment: In my case, I get it from Font Book, and this *might* be the reason why some fonts get properly installed but aren't showing up on *any* application... but I'm obviously speculating!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this, it is supposed to work on macOS Mojave 10.14.2. Since I updated to newer version(10.14.6) the warning is back.

```
    import PyQt5.QtWidgets as pyqt
    options = pyqt.QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= pyqt.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
```