# iOS Class is implemented in both framewoks One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

> objc[415]: Class DeviceType is implemented in both `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DeviceIdentity.framework/DeviceIdentity` (0x1b36a3908) and `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/02B183A2-F8F6-4F73-A915-6C9CD41E9299/app3.app/Frameworks/PVModel.framework/PVModel` (0x10238a650). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I tried to build my app in an iPad, but I get this error which dose not show up other iPads. as I see there, it is looking for that class in `/System` directory! which is wrong.
how can I solve this?

> Duplicate with [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999695/class-fifindersyncextensionhost-is-implemented-in-both-warning-in-xcode-si)

Comment: I had this similar issue when I mistakenly installed pod and manually added in code. In your case it could be using a class named DeviceType of your own conflicting with UIKit DeviceType predefined class.

Comment: it is not conflicting with UIKit! It is some PrivateFrameworks of the system

Comment: This happened to me too. Best to rename your own class then, too bad Apple has these little surprises sometimes.

Comment: yeah that is what I finally settled  to