# Error message Filedialog tkinter / FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I'm using filedialog with tkinter to browse a file in my Python application. When I click on 'browse' I have this message :

> objc[84539]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit
>   (0x7fff99d17cd0) and
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
>   (0x1103dfcd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Here is my "browse" function

```
def select_input_file(self):
        global inputFileName
        self.inputFileName =  fd.askopenfilename(initialdir = "./",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("all files","."),("txt files","*.txt")))
        if(lb.size() == 0):
            lb.insert(END,self.inputFileName.split("/")[-1])  #Inserts txt filename in listbox.
        else:
            lb.delete(0)
            lb.insert(END,self.inputFileName.split("/")[-1])
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the function invoked on *"click on 'browse'"*?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but a number of Tcl/Tk users encounter this warning (i.e. this isn't Tkinter-specific). I'm not sure anyone knows what to do about this warning other than [ignore it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47013488/4896937).