# What does "Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both mean" when running crashdump_viewer?

Tags: erlang, crash-dumps

I started the `crashdump_viewer` and started looking at my crashdump. Then at some point I got an error log. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

```
➜  Desktop erl
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.5.11] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V10.3.5.11  (abort with ^G)
1> l(crashdump_viewer).
{module,crashdump_viewer}
2> crashdump_viewer:st
start/0       start/1       start_link/0  stop/0        stop_debug/0

2> crashdump_viewer:start
start/0       start/1       start_link/0
2> crashdump_viewer:start().
objc[26293]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fffa1eec3d8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x1f551f50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
                                                                               ok
3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang doesn't have classes, so the class in question probably has something to do with "the viewer" software.   According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999695/class-fifindersyncextensionhost-is-implemented-in-both-warning-in-xcode-si), it's an Apple issue.